# import japanize_matplotlibでModuleNotFoundError:No module named 'japanize_matplotlib' のエラー

Tags: python, macos, pip

macです。ターミナルで `pip3 install japanize-matplotlib` を実行した後に、IDLE で `import japanize-matplotlib` を実行すると以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
ModuleNotFoundError:No module named  'japanize_matplotlib'
```

`pip install japanize_matplotlib` のコマンドも試しましたがだめでした。

`pip3 install japanize-matplotlib` のコマンドを実行すると以下のエラーが表示されます。

```
Requirement already satisfied: japanize-matplotlib in /Users/○○/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

恐らくpip3 でjapanize_matplotliをインストールしたPythonとIDLEでのPythonが違う？のだと思いますが、調べてみても詳しくわかりません。

Comment: anacondaをお使いのようですね。anacondaであればspyderやjupyterを使った方が良いのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 何を入力したらどんなエラーメッセージが出たのか, 正しく記してください。`import japanize-matplotlib` だと構文エラーになるはず。複数の Pythonが入ってるなら, `import sys; print(sys.executable)` などでどこに入ってるかそれぞれ確認しておくとよいかも

Comment: `IDLE`をどんな方法・手順で起動しているかが肝心なのでは？ こんな記事が参考になるかもしれません。[Idle and Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50278398/9014308)